# addition of physical address upon paper acceptance

Tags: publications

A paper was reviewed, sent back for revision and resubmitted. Is it allowed to add a new address (current) when a paper is just accepted?

Comment: This may be country or field dependent, but, assuming the work on the paper was mostly done at the old address, one would indicate a current address as a footnote (style varies by journal). Adding such in proof is usually OK.

Comment: will a footnote be useful in promotion to tenure?

Comment: That is a very different question that can only be answered by the particular institution. But if your tenure decision comes down to one paper, which by date of acceptance might not count (or show the work performed at that institution), you are probably on thin ice already. Properly attribute work. Otherwise your graduating students might just switch their affiliations at the last moment, taking credit towards tenure away from you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably.  But only the journal can say and you should just ask them ASAP.  Worst that can happen is "no".

Edit:  removed non-SE compliant sarcastic remarks.